# How to play youtube with JS after a timeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a youtube video on my website and want it to start playing after 5 sec user is on my site.

Is it possible with JS / jQuery? Anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/dyLAC

You just need to replace the below code in above link

```
$('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {

    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();

  });
```

with

```
setTimeout(function(ev) {

    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();

  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple :

```js
 setInterval(function(e){
   $('#video')[0].src += '?autoplay=1';
   e.preventDefault();
 }, 5000);
```

```html
<iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2mWaqsC3U7k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Check this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96qgfg4w/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use correct way to do this.

For example, you can do it with pure JS and YouTube Player API:

```
<iframe id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1" width="400" height="300"></iframe>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>
    var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }, 5000)
    }
</script>
```

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hv4bpbys/2/

You can find more information [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player)